# Создание игрового мира на весь экран на phaser js

Tags: phaser-framework

создал игровой экземпляр

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });
```

1) Почему отчет игрового мира начинается не с левого верхнего края, а будто бы на координатах x=10 y=10 ?

2) Как сделать на весь экран игровой мир?(то как я сделал выше window.innerWidth window.innerHeight приходится прокручивать чуток, а нужно без прокрутки! )

В Phaser есть:

```
 this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
 this.scale.pageAlignHorisontally = true; 
 this.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
```

но от них эффект такой же ( прокрутка остается, и начало игрового мира не с левого верхнего края)

Объясните пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Решение было найдено. Оказывается нужно было добавить стили в основной документ html

```
<style>
       body {
                  padding: 0px;
                  margin: 0px;
                  background: black;
                }
                </style>
```